# what's the connection, if any, between the graviton and the newly detected gravitational waves?

Tags: gravitational-waves

Is there any connection between the graviton, which is listed as a hypothetical particle, and the newly detected gravitational waves?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are both postulated by two different theories. Gravitons by standard model, and gravitational waves by general relativity. There is no theoretical link between the two at this time.

Comment: there are no gravitons in the standard model

Comment: I disagree, gravitational waves would have to be a superposition of freely propagating gravitons if they exists! The question is more about the existence of quantized gravity with a graviton, which would imply that classical gravitational waves would be a limit case of graviton superpositions.

Answer (score 2):

If wave-particle duality holds for gravity then the graviton would be to gravitational waves what the photon is to electromagnetic waves.

Comment: docscience, please excuse the "tone" of the question but I have to ask.  I realize that all "particles" have the wave/particle duality quality to them, but assuming that your comment is true, what is the approximate "size" of the "particle" associated with a graviton?

Comment: The graviton is the spin 2 particle obtained when weak field, linearized GR is quantized. OTOH, gravitational waves are the result of full strength, non-linear GR.  The graviton, if it exists, would obey the Planck and de Broglie relations. It would have zero size as a particle and travel at the speed of light.

Comment: @PeterDiehr This seems false. Don't you obtain gravitational waves precisely when linearizing GR?

Comment: Regarding the answer, first, I think it is ill-advised in general to rely on the concept of wave-particle duality for intuition in QM. Second, the wave/particle duality would imply that the graviton itself can have both properties of a particle and a wave, depending if its state is closer to an eigenstate of position or momentum. The classical gravitational waves would only be remotely implicated in this duality.